# OpenAL error: 40964 when running an executable

Tags: debian, audio, executable, libraries

I recently installed the missing libraries for an executable, but I have problems when I run it. It doesn't sound and these are the errors I get when I run it from the terminal.

```
OpenAL error: 40964 (SoundHardware::Tick)
OpenAL error: 40964 (Audio_Tick Start)
OpenAL error: 40964 (Audio_Tick End)
```

This is the `ldd` of the binary:

```
user@debian:~/Games/Undertale$ ldd runner 
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f4c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7daf000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf7d90000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xf7d89000)
    libGL.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0xf7d23000)
    libopenal.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopenal.so.1 (0xf7c2d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7b27000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7b1c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7afb000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7af5000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xf7912000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf78fd000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf77ad000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0xf77a0000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0xf7725000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0xf76c1000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf76a3000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf74c5000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f4e000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0xf74a1000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0xf743f000)
    libsndio.so.7.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsndio.so.7.0 (0xf742c000)
    libatomic.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libatomic.so.1 (0xf7422000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf73f2000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xf73e6000)
    libasound.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0xf72cc000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0xf72ad000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf72a8000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf72a1000)
```

How can I solve to have sound when the binary is running?

Comment: It would help to let us know what the program actually is, and how you're running it. Are you even giving it the correct type of audio files, in the correct way?

Comment: @Kusalananda the program is a game and the audio files are in `~/Games/Undertale/assets/`. All the audio files are in `.ogg` format

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by installing `libpulse` as found [here](http://unixboard.de/threads/kein-sound-im-spiel-openal-error.56093) (german link). My problem was also with the undertale game, as you mentioned in the comment.